How to write a wait decorator that applies to all functions in web utilities class?
Here's my WebUtils class:
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def wait_for_element(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        loctype, locvalue = args[-1]
        driver = args[0]
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((loctype, locvalue)))
        element.click()
        return func(driver, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper




class WebUtils:

    @wait_for_element
    def sendKeys(self, driver, string, element):
        loctype, locvalue = element
        print(loctype, locvalue)
        driver.find_element(loctype, locvalue).send_keys(string)

    @wait_for_element
    def clickElement(self, driver, element):
        loctype, locvalue = element
        print(loctype, locvalue)
        driver.find_element(loctype, locvalue).click()


Also, PFA the image of my file/folder tree. My goal is to write a decorator that takes care of explicit waiting for all elements. (I know this can easily be accomplished by modifying the functions, but I'd like to do it with decorators because isn't that what the decorators in python are for?).
I am getting this error:
FAILED test/test_register.py::TestReg::test_launch_url[test_case1] - AttributeError: 'WebUtils' object has no attribute 'find_element'      
FAILED test/test_register.py::TestReg::test_launch_url[test_case2] - AttributeError: 'WebUtils' object has no attribute 'find_element' 

I even tried to put the decorator inside the class. That didn't help either
I am not even able to understand why this is a question of find_element being an attribute of WebUtils class. Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Here's the folder tree:


You don't want the .click() to be in wrapper(). For an element you are going to click, you should wait for clickable. For all other elements you are going to interact with, you should wait for visible.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

how do you execute these functions? It seems you send wrong value as driver to sendKeys and clickElement. It looks like you send WebUtils as driver. Did you create instance item = WebUtils() and run item.sendKeys(driver, ...) ? If you run it as WebUtils.sendKeys(driver, ...) then don't use self

You can wrap methods with WebDriverWait and expected_conditions like this to simplify your scripts and have automatic waiting:
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from unittest import TestCase

class RefinedRawSelenium(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = None
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        if "linux" in sys.platform:
            options.add_argument("--headless=new")
        options.add_experimental_option(
            "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"],
        )
        prefs = {
            "credentials_enable_service": False,
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        service = Service(service_args=["--disable-build-check"])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.driver:
            try:
                if self.driver.service.process:
                    self.driver.quit()
            except Exception:
                pass

    def wait_for_element_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was not visible after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def wait_for_element_clickable(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was not visible/clickable after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def wait_for_element_not_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.invisibility_of_element((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Element {%s} was still visible after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def open(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

    def click(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        el = self.wait_for_element_clickable(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        el.click()

    def type(self, selector, text, by="css selector", timeout=10):
        el = self.wait_for_element_clickable(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        el.clear()
        if not text.endswith("\n"):
            el.send_keys(text)
        else:
            el.send_keys(text[:-1])
            el.submit()

    def assert_element(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)

    def assert_text(self, text, selector="html", by="css selector", timeout=7):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        self.assertIn(text, el.text)

    def assert_exact_text(self, text, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        self.assertEqual(text, el.text)

    def assert_element_not_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=7
    ):
        self.wait_for_element_not_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)

    def test_add_item_to_cart(self):
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        self.type("#user-name", "standard_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce\n")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_text("Products", "span.title")
        self.click('button[name*="backpack"]')
        self.click("#shopping_cart_container a")
        self.assert_exact_text("Your Cart", "span.title")
        self.assert_text("Backpack", "div.cart_item")
        self.click("#remove-sauce-labs-backpack")
        self.assert_element_not_visible("div.cart_item")
        self.click("#react-burger-menu-btn")
        self.click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("input#login-button")

# When run with "python" instead of "pytest" or "python -m unittest"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from unittest import main
    main()

This was described in the Python presentation at SeleniumConf 2023 (YouTube Playlist) as the optimal way to build Python Selenium frameworks that use simplified scripts and have automatic waiting.

Hi Michael Mintz, thank you but I am quite aware of this way of handling things. I am interested only in knowing the decorator way of doing things. Could you please let me know if you know that? Thanks again!

For that, you'll need to create a decorator that takes args so that you can pass in the selector to wait for. Demo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/7058266
